# Defining a ClusterRoleBinding for Terraform service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

So I have a GCP service account that is `Kubernetes Admin` and `Kubernetes Cluster Admin` in the GCP cloud console.

I am now trying to give this terraform service account the `ClusterRole` role in GKE to manage all namespaces via following terraform configuration:

```
data "google_service_account" "terraform" {
  project    = var.project_id
  account_id = var.terraform_sa_email
}

# Terraform needs to manage cluster
resource "google_project_iam_member" "terraform-gke-admin" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/container.admin"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${data.google_service_account.terraform.email}"
}

# Terraform needs to manage K8S RBAC
# https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control#iam-rolebinding-bootstrap
resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "terraform_clusteradmin" {
  depends_on = [
    google_project_iam_member.terraform-gke-admin,
  ]

  metadata {
    name = "cluster-admin-binding-terraform"
  }

  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "ClusterRole"
    name      = "cluster-admin"
  }

  subject {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "User"
    name      = data.google_service_account.terraform.email
  }

  # must create a binding on unique ID of SA too
  subject {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "User"
    name      = data.google_service_account.terraform.unique_id
  }
}
```

However, this always returns the following error:

```
Error: clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "client" cannot create resource "clusterrolebindings" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
│ 
│   with module.kubernetes[0].kubernetes_cluster_role_binding.terraform_clusteradmin,
│   on kubernetes/terraform_role.tf line 15, in resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "terraform_clusteradmin":
│   15: resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "terraform_clusteradmin" {
```

Any ideas what goes wrong here?
Could this be related to using Google Groups RBAC?

```
  authenticator_groups_config {
    security_group = "gke-security-groups@${var.acl_group_domain}"
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data "google_client_config" "provider" {}
provider "kubernetes" {
  cluster_ca_certificate = module.google.cluster_ca_certificate
  host                   = module.google.cluster_endpoint
  token                  = data.google_client_config.provider.access_token
}
```